# How to clear all the notifications from notification bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have to clear all the Remote/Local notifications from the notification bar when the user logs out from the app without clearing by his/her own. I'm using this code to clear the notifications but it isn't working for me this is my code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: Where are you writing this code?

Comment: In log out action @Sim

Comment: This won't remove any remote notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is correct. Still you can try this.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375355/clear-app-badge-with-local-notifications).